# Why do DOM additions with appendChild display on the browser but not in the source?

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

I am adding styles dynamically with appendChild and they work but they don't appear in the source of the markup (despite calling appendChild after window.onload).

```
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = `h1{color:red;}`;
window.onload = function(){document.head.appendChild(style);}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/QK9sE0/9wtkr7mo/

[image]

Comment: The source is the actual HTML text that was downloaded when the page loaded. If you want to see the actual DOM tree, look at the Elements tab, or serialize the DOM to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the source is the source and not a live representation of the current state of the DOM.

If you followed the instructions to build a LEGO model and then added some more pieces, it wouldn’t change the instructions.

Most browsers have a set of Developer Tools with an Inspect tab that will show a live representation of the current state of the DOM.

Comment: ... which, ironically, is often mistakenly called "the source" by developers.